# Are the Local Government Area wards of New South Wales available in a vector format?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, elections, australia

I'm looking for a vector (i.e. GeoPackage, shapefile, Geojson etc etc) format dataset of the wards in New South Wales. These are the electoral districts for the Local Government Areas.

An example of the boundaries I'm interested in can be seen [here] in purple.(http://pastvtr.elections.nsw.gov.au/LGE2017/inner-west/map.htm?showMap=true&mode=PP&ID=LG1701-057&fullname=Inner%20West&ward=)s

I'm aware of [this site](http://www.tallyroom.com.au/data) but the data doesn't quite match the official source when comparing counts of wards by LGA.

Answer (score 2):

Electoral boundaries from 2015 are available on the [website of the New South Wales Electoral Commission](http://www.elections.nsw.gov.au/about_elections/electoral_boundaries/electoral_maps/gda94_geographical_midmif_files).

> GDA94 Geographical MID/MIF Files
>
> New South Wales electoral boundaries for the 2015 State election are
>   available here as GDA94 geographical MapInfo mid/mif polygons and are
>   supplied 'as is'.  This can be used in software such as MapInfo, ARC
>   GIS or similar.
>
> These boundaries have been sourced by the Electoral Districts
>   Commission and should be suitable for most purposes.
>
> GDA94 geographical MapInfo mid/mif polygons (ZIP 4.6MB)

Here's a direct link to [download the electoral boundaries](http://www.elections.nsw.gov.au/__data/assets/file/0019/221158/GIS_Files.zip).

Comment: Thanks for these, I'm only on my phone right now so can't check, but I believe these are the electoral districts for the 56th Parliament of New South Wales, rather than the wards which are the electoral districts of the local government areas, which is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Sorry for the slow follow up on this. These aren't what I'm looking for, but thanks for the suggestion. To clarify I need the electoral boundaries for the _Local Government Areas_ within NSW rather than the electoral boundaries of NSW.

Comment: You should edit your question with that information. Don't expect people to mine through the comments to figure out what you need.

Comment: I think it already said it in the question: ` These are the electoral districts for the Local Government Areas.` Second sentence of the first paragraph. I'd be happy to accept an edit if you think it could be phrased more clearly.